# Is this post by a "Watco Rep" appropriate, or is it spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

Check out this late answer: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/158011/27773

It's posted by "John - Watco Rep": https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/97374/jon-watco-rep

The answer suggests A Watco Universal NuFiT, and includes a link to a Watco "Universal Sell Sheet" for the product.

Is this appropriate, or is this spam?

Comment: Looks to me like https://xkcd.com/810/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the username indicates an affiliation, he really needs to be explicit about this. Charcoal noted this and made a comment to that affect. [This is the Meta.SE policy on self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity). Particularly [the Robert Harvey response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182259/244695)

> Can it be done properly? Absolutely. The way you do it is to ask the question, "Are you talking to your audience with a clear view of their needs, or are you talking at them, with a clear view of yours?" There is a real need (within the context of a well-worded, constructive question) to plug products, if it is relevant to the question and a reasonably complete answer is provided.
>
> How is this determined by moderators? Well, in large part, we ask: are you contributing positively to the community, or are you just here to promote your product? Boiled down to its essence, it resolves to one remarkably simple idea:
>
> > Are your answers primarily bare links to your product?

So it's not a bare link, but even if this isn't ultimately spam, I'm not sure it answers the question. We can distill the answer down to

> You might have problems if you try a different model from the drain. But our universal fit works all the time! Here's a brochure about it...

Leaves a bad taste in my mouth. Might need low quality deletion.

Comment: Thanks. I agree on the "bad taste", but after some thought I think the answer is OK. It's a real company, with an appropriately-named user contributing real text, not just link spam. I'm leaving it alone (although my opinion may change if I see much more of this kind of post).

Answer (score 2):

My take on this is that giving that answer to an almost six year old question makes it look more like self promotional spam than a helpful answer to a new question from today or yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few people on here with an affiliation in their name or picture.   I would never trust a word any of these people say - sorry just how I am.   SE should not allow either but not my company.

I would personally take anything he says as spam because if someone is going the step of advertising here how can you trust them to offer advice that might not lead to them making income?